# Eliminar advertencia "<link rel=preload> has an invalid `href` value"

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy cargando de forma dinámica una imagen para el fondo de pantalla, pero **precargándola**; con esto, busco mostrarla de una vez, y no poco a poco según se carga, aunque la velocidad de red sea lenta. Para ello, tengo el siguiente `html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
.background {
  /* background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; */
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
    </style>
  </meta>
  <body class="background">
  </body>
</html>
```

Una vez cargado el documento y parseado el DOM, obtengo un archivo `config.json` en el que se me indica la imagen de fondo. Con esto, creo un `<link rel="preload" ...>` dinamicamente:

```
const utils = {
  background: {
    set: function( url ) {
      var ele;

      if( !utils.background.$link ) {
        ele = document.createElement( 'link' );

        ele.setAttribute( 'rel', 'preload' );
        ele.setAttribute( 'as', 'image' );
        ele.setAttribute( 'href', url );
        ele.onload = onImageLoaded;

        utils.background.$link = ele;

        document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( ele );
      } else {
        ele = utils.background.$link;
        ele.onload = onImageLoaded;
        ele.setAttribute( 'href', url )
      }

      function onImageLoaded( ) {
        document.getElementsByClassName( 'background' )[0].style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
      }
    },
    cancel: function( ) {
      if( utils.background.$link ) utils.background.$link.removeAttribute( 'href' );
    }
  }
}
```

Funciona correctamente; aún limitando la velocidad de red, la imagen se muestra toda de golpe. El problema es la función `utils.background.cancel( )`. Esta función se usa para eliminar la imagen. En este caso, la imagen solo se usa durante el proceso de *login*. Una vez el usuario hace el ingreso correctamente, la imagen ha de ocultarse. **Pero, si se está cargando, quiero detener la carga**.

Llamando a esta función, ciertamente, **la carga se detiene**; pero en la consola del navegador aparece la advertencia

> <link rel=preload> has an invalid 'href' value

Entiendo que puede ser un *exceso de celo* del navegador, pero me parece ... poco profesional ir dejando avisos por ahí.

¿ Hay alguna otra forma de *cancelar* la carga de un elemento `<link rel="preload" ...>` **sin** eliminar su propiedad `href` ? O, en su defecto, sin que aparezca el mencionado *aviso* en la consola.

<sub>**Nota**: He intentado eliminar el atributo `backgroundImage` del `body` haciendo `delete document.getElementsByClassName( 'background' )[0].style.backgroundImage;`, pero esto **no** interrumpe la carga de la imagen.</sub>

Comment: Para precarga de imágenes suele ser mejor crear un elemento imagen ( `let img = new Image();` ) y asignarlo al destino al terminar la carga (`img.onload `), en este caso el cancel y cierre de la conexión no es un estándar http sino mas bien una implementación de los navegadores ( limpiar el src con `img.src = '';`). Por otro lado el rel="preload" en un elemento `link` sólo tiene sentido para disparar un fetch de un recurso antes de que comience el render de la página, si estás esperando al DOM para crear el link se pierde esa ventaja y sería mas simple crear una imagen en memoria.

Comment: @aloMalbarez El código es bastante mas largo y complicado que lo ahí mostrado. Es un método de carga en varias fases, con toda la GUI en javascript (el `<body>` está vacío) usando las [webix](https://docs.webix.com/). No puedo meter elementos en el `<body>`, así que la mejor forma que he encontrado es la que muestro: usando un `<style>` a medio formar, y completarlo luego desde Javascript. El `"preload"` es solamente para evitar mostrar la imagen poco a poco si la red es muy lenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al llamara a la función `utils.background.cancel()` estas eliminando la propiedad `href` haciendo así que se detenga la descarga de la imagen.

**Para evitar la advertencia**, en vez de eliminar la propiedad, **has de quitar la url de la imagen**.

Poner el `href` vacío también daría una advertencia por lo que puedes **poner un `href` válido pero inútil** como `"#"`.

A `background`, añade la función `clear` que cambie el `href`:

```
clear: function( ) {
    if( utils.background.$link ) utils.background.$link.setAttribute( 'href', '#' );
}
```

Comment: ¡ Eres una máquina ! xD